# security risk of MySQL query via PHP with no user input

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm writing a website that displays various information from a database on the home page such as the next event that the organization is putting on. This information gets selected from the db with no user input. There's just a siple query that retrieves the next event.

It seems like most of the security considerations I've seen have been regarding situations where a user is inputting something or outside data of some type is being processed. What considerations are there for a situation like this where I am handling only my own data and the PHP will all have run its course by the time the user loads the page?

It seems like there wouldn't be much else to worry about assuming I'm using MySQLi and not doing anything out of the ordinary for a simple query.

Comment: Always sanitize your input.

Comment: Even if the data provided to your queries is from the application and not a user, you should still be in the habit of using prepared statements anyway.

Comment: Close this question and head over to [ircmaxell](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/search/label/Securityhttp://blog.ircmaxell.com/search/label/Security) and spend a good time reading about security with php and mysql.

Comment: show us what code you are using. The question is a bit generalized and if you shows us what code your using it's easier to elaborate on specific issues. There are a million ways you could be creating your sql statement and doing your MySQL query without user input, so 1 answer does not provide a global solution to all those situations, hence code of yours would narrow it down.

Comment: `simple query`, `next event` - how it recognize its as next? some id in http request?

Comment: User input is not `human into the form input`. Any parts of your http-request(get, post, cookies, headers etc) are user-input. because all of them can be cooked and sended by any user(even without browser at all).

Comment: Like I said, there is no user input. As in the query is hardcoded and runs exactly the same way every time the page is loaded.

Comment: @vp_arth that's but a deadly delusion. HTTP requests has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: @pocketg99, so, obviously, there is nothing to change your database query. You're in safe about sql-injections.

Comment: This is not a question about injections. I know I don't have to worry about that. This is a question about other potential aspects of PHP and MySQL security.

Comment: Your shoud care more about other sides of security, Check the list of open vulnerabilities for soft you are using (`apache`, `openssl`, `php` etc). What external interfaces are you expose? Is it just http? https? May be your mysql serves incoming connections too? There are bunch of possibilities. `What with my security?` question is always too wide.

Comment: Then this question is FAR open-ended and should be closed.

Comment: Good old SO. People as kind and helpful as ever.

Answer (score 1):

A proper SQL handling has absolutely nothing to do with whatever "user input". There are no such words when you program a database interaction.

There are 2 rules for the proper SQL handling, and none of them ever contain whatever "user input".

1. All strings and numbers that are coming from variables in your script, have to be represented as placeholders.
2. All other query parts have to be hardcoded in your script.

So, judging by your description, as long as your SQL is 100% hardcoded, it is perfectly safe.